# Ordering characters across a list of strings

Tags: c#, sorting

I feel like I need some kind of sorting algorithm for this but the general idea is that I was trying last night to build a sudoku game as a learning exercise. I managed to generate a "board" (being a list of 9 strings each having a different arrangement of digits 1-9).

```
private void GeneratePuzzle()
{
    var numbers = "123456789";
    var rng = new Random();

    // Generate 9 strings representing the rows of the grid.
    List<string> board = new List<string>(9);

    // Track the numbers used in each column.
    List<HashSet<char>> columnSets = Enumerable.Range(0, 9)
        .Select(_ => new HashSet<char>())
        .ToList();

    for (var row = 0; row < 9; row++)
    {
        var item = "";

        for (var col = 0; col < 9; col++)
        {
            var possibleNumbers = numbers.Except(columnSets[col]).Except(item);
            if (possibleNumbers.Any())
            {
                var digit = possibleNumbers.ElementAt(rng.Next(possibleNumbers.Count()));
                item += digit;
                columnSets[col].Add(digit);
            }
            else
            {
                // If no available numbers, reset the row and start over.
                item = "";
                foreach (var set in columnSets)
                {
                    set.Clear();
                }
                col = -1; // Reset column index to restart from the beginning
            }
        }

        board.Add(item);
    }
}
```

Example output:

> 192837465
> 385629817
> 569187423
> 724638951
> 816579342
> 162948735
> 462895713
> 837926514
> 925741386

This output gives us a board in which the rows all fit correctly, but columns and 3x3 subgrids duplicate numbers.

I thought about possibly running through each string and comparing it character-for-character against the others across all 9 list items but this seems inefficient at best and I can't work out a reasonable way to write it anyway.

So how would one go about arranging these unique strings so that they make the necessary 1-9 combinations on columns and 3x3 as well as the rows?

Comment: You do realize you're far from the first person to tackle generating Sudoku boards programmatically? Unless you're against doing so, I'd strongly encourage you to search for existing solutions and see how they've been done. I'm finding plenty of results for Python and Javascript, fewer for C#. But it should allow you to see how others tackle the algorithmic parts of the exercise.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I have looked at a few. That's where I got the idea to generate strings of 9 characters in a list. I also tried generating a single string which is 81 characters long. The problem is always the same. Additionally, being full applications, most examples include a lot of background noise that have nothing to do with the problem I'm trying to solve. So overall, not a helpful comment, thanks.

Comment: I don't think the path u chose is the best. I would recommend to work with numbers and  use a backtracking algorithm.  With numbers is easy to add or subtract in the backtracking way to find the next step to move forward or to return.  You have here the c# implementation https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sudoku-backtracking-7/